# what's the grammar of ださん?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I read in a Japanese tale ([kachikachi yama](http://pangeranpenguin.blogspot.fr/2014/07/cerita-bahasa-jepang-kachikachiyama.html)) :

An old man (a peasant) is happy since he just catched a tanuki and says to his wife :

> 「それじゃ ちょっくら まちへ かいものに いってくるから たぬきが **にげださんように** きをつけておくれ。」

translation from Tom Ray and Sachiko Matsubara :

> "I will go to the town for a little while to shop and return
>   please be careful that the raccoon does not run away."

---

ちょっくら is analysed as ちょっと ([a "country form"](http://pangeranpenguin.blogspot.fr/2014/07/cerita-bahasa-jepang-kachikachiyama.html)).

I analyse にげださんように as 逃げる【にげる】(run away) + ださん + ように. I don't understand [ださん](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1F) (or maybe [たさん](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1F) ?) : is this a verbal form ? I read [here](http://pangeranpenguin.blogspot.fr/2014/07/cerita-bahasa-jepang-kachikachiyama.html) that : "ださん = do not begin" .

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「[逃]{に}げ[出]{だ}さ**ん**」＝「逃げ出さ**ない**」 = "***not*** run away"

「ん」 is a negation auxiliary verb.  The dictionary form is 「ぬ」.

See ぬ[助動] in https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AC-593884#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

「～～ように」 means "so that ~~".

「たぬきが逃げ出さんように」 = "so that the racoon will not run away".

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask you if 逃げ出さないように exist ?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Historically, ぬ/ん is just older than ない.

Comment: Thank you. Reïko Shimamori (Grammaire japonaise systématique, II.156) explains exactly what you said and adds that "-n is often used in the West side of the Japanese archipelago".